# Karate: I would like to assert to match parts of response

Tags: karate

Karate: I would like to assert  to match parts of response

I am getting the following response:
12:10:33.960 [print] Kyc Status changed from NotStarted to Accepted.Reason: Output Address AddressLine : 6927 14TH AVE

But I would like to only make assertion to match part of the response.
e.g.: "Kyc Status changed from NotStarted to Accepted."

Comment: It's a response of content type `text/plain`? `match response contains` allows to test if the response contains text elements.

Comment: Thank Peter for quick response, Yes, the response is text. Can I do partial match instead of the entire text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following examples should solve your problem:

```
    Scenario: Matching text
      * def yourResponse = "12:10:33.960 [print] Kyc Status changed from NotStarted to Accepted.Reason: Output Address AddressLine : 6927 14TH AVE"
      * match yourResponse contains "NotStarted to Accepted"
      * match yourResponse !contains "does not contain"
      * assert new RegExp("NotStarted to Accepted").test(yourResponse)
```

Needless to say, that you can use any regex with the `assert new RegExp` construct.

Comment: Thanks Peter, it worked. I am fairly new with Karate Framework but I am really enjoying the tool and support

Comment: If you like karate, you have to check out vscode and the [vscode karate runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kirkslota.karate-runner) with the new debug feature!

Comment: assert new RegExp is not working for version 1.1.0 @Peter kindly suggest what other way can we do partial match